# Why are my .NET processes running as 32 bit when using the 64 bit installutil?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

We have a C# console application that we have installed as a Windows service. The target 64 bit machine is running Windows Server 2012. We used the 64 bit installutil utility:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>installutil -i C:\Services\MainService\Service.exe
```

However when I see the process running in the Task Manager, it shows it running as 32 bit process:

[image: Snapshot_of_task_manager_32bit_process]

Any ideas why this is, and how I can get the process to run as 64 bit?

I saw this question posted here, but no one has answered it yet:

> [Why is my 64 bit service running as 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32080610/why-is-my-64-bit-service-running-as-32-bit)

Comment: Sounds like the application (itself) was compiled to run on either configuration, or explicitly as 32-bit only.  I don't think this has anything to do with InstallUtil.

Comment: The installer is a separate exe from the thing it's installing. There are probably times where you need a 64bit installer to install a 64bit program, but otherwise they are separate things where a 64bit installer can install a 32bit program no problem. For Visual Studio, when you build your own program you have to make sure it's set to 64bit--don't set to "Any CPU" and don't check "Prefer 32bit".

Comment: I researched the "Prefer 32bit" option this weekend. I guess, we are building using TeamCity MSBuild plugin, and we pass in the "Release|Any CPU" configuration to MSBuild. Do you know if it would pick up the "Prefer 32bit"? I ran corflags against the DLLs, and found it set 32BITREQ and 32BITPREF to 0.

Comment: Have you considered explicitly compiling x64 (rather than 'any')?

Comment: "I ran corflags against the DLLs" -- Shouldn't you run it against the .exe in the screenshot?

Comment: Just ran corflags against the .EXE; looks like that is the cause. But how is this being set in the TeamCity build? 
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 0x20003
ILONLY    : 1
32BITREQ  : 0
32BITPREF : 1
Signed    : 0

Comment: I hope I don't have to manually remove the "Prefer 32bit" setting from each individual project in my solution files. :-(

Comment: Found this: http://sushihangover.github.io/corflags-cross-platform-release-on-github/. Looks like I can run the tool to clear the 32BITPREF flag from the executable. Is this bad practice?

Comment: Should be fine. The `.csproj` files themselves are normal text files, you could use `File.ReadAllLines()`, `File.WriteAllLines()` to change all of them yourself, but that tool already did the work for you. Have a proper backup first, and you can also test it on a few files and diff them to see what it actually changes (hopefully just the one `Prefer32Bit` line gets changed, though the tool might automatically change whitespace and other things..). P.s., unless you put @name, like @JoseChavez, no one gets notified of your comment unless you made the post. I only saw it from checking back here.

Comment: @Quantic I solved the issue by clearing the flag using corflags.exe. Do you want to post an answer, or should I just answer my own question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using CorFlags.exe to remove the 32BITPREF flag from the EXEs. I just setup a build step in TeamCity to cover this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\"CorFlags.exe Service.exe /nologo /32BITPREF-
```

I think the better approach would be to manually go through every project and disable that flag. As someone mentioned, a simple grep and sed would most likely do the trick.

---

### Update

Clearing the "Prefer 32 Bit" flag is a better option. This ensures that 64 bit version is compiled, and no need for custom script in the TeamCity build configuration.

Comment: Hmm, no, you simply need to correct the jitter forcing options, only in the service EXE project.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option and ensure that the Platform target setting is AnyCPU.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: @HansPassant Judging from his comments I think he has 50+ projects to change and he doesn't want to go to "Project > Properties > Build tab" 50 times.

Comment: As noted, only the settings in the EXE project matters.  Since it starts first, it locks in the bitness of the service process.

Comment: And don't forget to change in both Debug and Release as I just found out...